# How to make the top bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why when I write this code the application crashing?

```java
    Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.scroll_top_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

This is the xml code

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DisplayInformations">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/scroll_top_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the java code

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_informations);

        Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.scroll_top_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
```

```java
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_informations,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

"You may find a mistake in my question because I am new to the stack over flow platform"

Comment: If its crashing, post your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one article: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar

And also this one:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Comment: I did not find the solution

Comment: Can you please post link to you github sources for this task, so I could run it?\